# Magnitude of a dipole moment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, torque, dipole-moment

I am now learning Electromagnetism, and I am doing the practice question. However I am stuck in the following question.

A uniform electric field has a dipole placed in it. If you rotate the dipole you find that the maximum torque it experiences is $7.9 × 10^{-26} N·m$. If the electric field is generated by two parallel plates separated by $11.8cm$ subject to a potential difference of $33.1 V$, what is the magnitude of the dipole moment $p$.

After checking lecture notes, I know the following (same as the one in my lecture notes) [image: Image same as lecture notes]
Would someone explain to me if the figure above is related to my question or not.

p is pretty sure stands for moment, F is force, q is the charge, E is electric field.
I am not sure if the question said 11.8 cm is the distance of the particles or not.

Comment: Hi MathKnight and welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. See [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Should any check my work questions be made on topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) posts on meta for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $d\sin\phi$ is maximized when $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we find that the torque between the two particles is maximized when $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ where:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tau_{\textrm{max}}&=\frac{F_+d}{2}+\frac{F_-d}{2}\\
&=Eqd\\
&=Ep
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where in our last step we used the definition of the dipole moment. In addition, as the magnitude of the electric field in a parallel plate capacitor is given by $E=\frac{V}{l}$ we find that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tau_{\textrm{max}}&=Ep\\
&=\frac{Vp}{l}\\
\implies p&=\frac{\tau_{\textrm{max}}l}{V}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Substituting our given values we therefore find that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p&=\frac{\tau_{\textrm{max}}l}{V}\\
&=\frac{7.9\times 10^{-26}\times 0.118}{33.1}\textrm{ C m}\\
&\approx 2.82\times 10^{-28}\textrm{ C m}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Torque = P*E ( P & E are vectors, also * means cross product)

Since the torque is
 maximum P is perpendicular to E so we can forget about the cross product(sin90 = 1)
Torque given here = PE

In a capacitor 
E = potentia/distance between the plates

Therefore 
P = max torque/(V/D)

Comment: You could at least learn how to use LaTex you know...